# Is it possible to initialize .net core non-pcf deployed application with values from Config Server

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, cloud-foundry, pcf

I have a .net core app, hosted on PCF. Also I have Config Server installed.
I want to run locally with iis express this application and load same config values as it will have when deployed to pcf, and I do not want to deploy it to Pcf Dev as I want to debug it.
Is it possible? The only workaround I have is to fetch all variables into User managed secrets, but it's awful.

Comment: Are you using Steeltoe? If not, take a look at - https://steeltoe.io/. 
Steeltoe allows you to leverage all Spring Cloud Services [Config Server, Eureka Registry, Hystrix etc].

Comment: Yes, we use it and actually it work OK for the PCF-hosted apps. But Im looking for possiblity to connect Steeltoe to PCF Config Server without PCF Dev.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need PCF to use Steeltoe. Steeltoe is open source and so is Spring. Steeltoe libraries allow .net apps to leverage Spring Cloud functionality like Config, Eureka Registry etc. in a consistent fashion. 
Check out DZone article - https://dzone.com/articles/service-discovery-with-eureka-and-zuul

Comment: If you want to run spring cloud services locally, try out Spring Cloud CLI. – K.AJ 4 hours ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steeltoe and SCS Client look at the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable to load the configuration they use to talk with Config Server. On PCF, this environment variable is automatically populated with information based on the services that you bind to your app.

I do not know of any tool to manage/bind services locally, but you can always set environment variables manually. If you were to run `cf env <app>` for an app that is bound to your Config Server, it will list the contents of the `VCAP_SERVICES` env variable. Copy that output, paste it into an environment variable on your local machine. Fire up your app and Steeltoe or SCS Client should pick that information up automatically.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The idea is to have non-PCF hosted application running locally with the same parameters as in PCF with Cloud Config Server, and all this variables should be up to date.

Comment: Hey this worked. I put it in VSCode's launch.json file, in the `"env":{}` area. Just call the property `"VCAP_SERVICES"` and the value is a string of the JSON fragment from PCF. Make sure to escape your quotes and I think this will work.

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli - You will need to make sure the variable content stays up-to-date. When you run locally there is no platform (i.e. PCF) to do that for you. Best you could do would be to script it. For what it's worth, your SCS config won't change all that often. It shouldn't change unless you unbind/bind the service to your app. You could alternatively create a service key, which is it's own entity and that will never change, unless you delete the service key.  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/service-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to connect to the exact same config server, you can run the config server locally with Java or Docker and point it at the same back-end. The Steeltoe docs include [instructions for running the config server with Maven](https://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-configuration/#2-1-1-running-locally) and the Music Store sample includes [cmd](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/dev/MusicStore/dockerrun-configserver.cmd) and [sh](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/dev/MusicStore/dockerrun-configserver.sh) scripts that show running a config server via Docker, though they may be slightly out of date. The most recent way I've run the docker command is something like this:

`docker run --rm -ti -p 8888:8888 -v $PWD/config-repo:/config --name steeltoe-config steeltoeoss/configserver --spring.profiles.active=native`

from a location that contains a folder named `config-repo` with the relevant config files in that location.

Comment: actually my goal is to connect to the same server in nonPCF environment ) Because I do not have same access to git settings as ConfigServer does, but I wanna use same set of parameters.

Comment: If you want to connect to the server running in PCF from outside of PCF, you'll need to follow the answer from @daniel-mikusa -- you'll want to set both `VCAP_SERVICES` and `VCAP_APPLICATION`. That does assume that your workstation can reach into the network where the config server is running though.

Comment: But it means that all this values will be static, my hope was to kind of initializing my env with help of any service.

Comment: I've added an issue to the Steeltoe Tooling backlog to build something that can help with this scenario as this could fit in with some other work we're doing around improving the .NET experience with PCF.

In the meantime, this plugin might be of use https://github.com/jthomas/copyenv